# Pixel Buffer Object (PBO) does not work correctly

Tags: opengl, textures

I've written a very simple OpenGL application. Its goal is to load a texture and draw it on a plane using a PBO. If I use the function 'glTexSubImage2D' the plane is not textured and the function 'glGetError' returns the error '1281' (invalid value). However if I use the function 'glTexImage2D' my plane plane is textured correctly (and I have no error).

Here's the code for the texture loading :

```
#define OFFSET_BUFFER(offset) ((char*)NULL + offset)

void core::RootDevice::LoadTexture(char const *pFileName)
{
    SDL_Surface *pSurface = IMG_Load(pFileName);
    char *pPixels = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pSurface->pixels);
    uint32_t bytePerPixel = pSurface->format->BitsPerPixel;

    glGenTextures(1, &textureId);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    {
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        glGenBuffers(1, &pboID);
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, pboID);
        {
            unsigned int bufferSize = pSurface->w * pSurface->h * 3 * sizeof(unsigned char);

            glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, bufferSize, 0, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
            glBufferSubData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0, bufferSize, pPixels);

            glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, pSurface->w,                //NOT OK : ERROR 1281
                pSurface->h, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));

            /*glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pSurface->w,               //OK : NO ERROR
                pSurface->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, OFFSET_BUFFER(0));*/
        }
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

And the rendering code :

```
void core::RootDevice::Render(void)
{
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);
    {
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
            glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glEnd();
    }
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

And the result is the followings:

[image]

I'm really lost. Does anyone can help me, please ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Your buffer, and the amount of chars you copy is too few. You are missing the fact there are 3 components, each 1 char in size, so you need a '* 3' in there.

Comment: Thank you for this remark. I fixed it. But I still have no texture mapped on my plane. I edited my post.

Comment: A little detail, not related to your problem: you are using a static_cast to convert the void pointer from SDL to a char pointer, i.e.: `char *pPixels = static_cast<char*>(pSurface->pixels);` whereas the correct would be a `reinterpret_cast`. Most compilers wouldn't even let you use a static cast in this case.

Comment: I think it might be a memory alignment issue. Please try adding `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);` to the top of your function, before creating the PBO. Also, take a look at the documentation of `glMapBuffer` and `GL_MIN_MAP_BUFFER_ALIGNMENT` to know more about the alignment requirements. http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/docbook4/xhtml/glMapBuffer.xml

Comment: Thanks again for your advices :). I fixed the problem (without the glPixelSorei call -> I tried without success) by doing a 'glTexImage2D' call. I have no error with this function. But if I use 'glTexSubImage2D' I have the error '1281'. I know that it corresponds to an invalid value but I don't understand why because the other function works!

Comment: The goal of my function 'LoadTexture' is only to create a new texture and not update it. So I simplified my code using the same manner to create VBO (I know that PBO and VBO have the same working system). So I edited my post. But I still have the same error for the 'glTexSubImage2D' and it still works with the 'glTexImage2D' call.

Comment: I tried without PBO usage. I simply loaded my texture with classic way and this is still the same problem. There is an error with 'glTexSubImage2D'. The same one. Only the function 'glTexImage2D' works correctly! Thanks again in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected behaviour.

If you look over your code, you'll see that you're getting a new texture name, binding it, then calling glTexSubImage.

The problem here is that when you call glTexSubImage **the texture does not actually exist yet**.

Textures are not created by glGenTextures; all that glGenTextures does is give you a free texture object name for use in subsequent calls.  The texture doesn't get created ("specified" in OpenGL terminology) until you make the first glTexImage call.

So hence the fact that glTexImage works but glTexSubImage doesn't:

- glTexImage is actually creating the texture successfully for the first time.
- glTexSubImage is trying to update a texture that does not exist yet.

---

Some general comments.

You don't actually need a PBO for this; you'll get the same result by just calling glTexImage directly (it may even be a little faster as you're not going through an intermediate object).  PBOs as a rule aren't useful if your usage pattern is to immediately update the texture after updating the PBO.

If all you want to do is create a new texture but not initialize it with any data you can call:

> glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, pSurface->w, pSurface->h, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);

Consider using *format* GL_BGRA and *type* GL_UNSIGNED_INT_8_8_8_8_REV for a faster transfer; yes, it's more data but it will more closely match the driver's internal representation and the driver will be more likely to do a direct transfer to the GPU rather than having to do any internal format conversions of it's own.  This is, of course, irrelevant if you're just initializing a texture with NULL data.

Comment: Ok it's logical :). Thank you very much for all your explanations ! Bye.